# Javascript dom manipulation memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, memory-leaks

Hi I have created a dom using raw javascript DOM:

Javascript code:

```
var parentElm = document.createElement("div");
var child1 = document.createElement("p");
var child2 = document.createElement("p");

parentElm.id = "parent";
child1.id = "child1";
child2.id = "child2";

child1.innerHTML = "Hello";
child2.innerHTML = "world"; // Is it a good way 

parentElm.appendChild(child1);
parentElm.appendChild(child2);
document.body.appendChild(parentElm);
```

The resulted HTML is:

```
<div id="parent">
    <p id="child1">Hello</p>
    <p id="child2">World</p>
</div>
```

Now when I want to remove the above section, I do as following.

```
document.body.removeChild(parentElm);
```

Here I am afraid of javascript memory leak.

- If I am removing parent element from body, does it totally removed
  from memory. ?
- If I am removing parent element from body, does it's
  child elements are also removed from memory by garbage collector automatically. Or I need to remove
  child elements manually ?
- Is using innerHTML in the above code is  a good way (child1.innerHTML = "Hello";)

Please help me in javascript dom manipulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I am removing parent element from body, does it totally removed from memory. ?

**If** your `parentElm`, `child1`, and `child2` variables are no longer in scope or you've set them to another value, yes.

> If I am removing parent element from body, does it's child elements are also removed from memory by garbage collector automatically. Or I need to remove child elements manually ?

If your `child1` and `child2` variables are no longer in scope or you've set them to another value, yes, removing the parent is all you need to do to remove the children and allow them to be cleanned up.

> Is using innerHTML in the above code is a good way (child1.innerHTML = "Hello";)

It's fine, and common practice.

So there's no memory leak here, for instance:

```
function addParagraphs() {
    var parentElm = document.createElement("div");
    var child1 = document.createElement("p");
    var child2 = document.createElement("p");

    parentElm.id = "parent";
    child1.id = "child1";
    child2.id = "child2";

    child1.innerHTML = "Hello";
    child2.innerHTML = "world"; // Is it a good way 

    parentElm.appendChild(child1);
    parentElm.appendChild(child2);
    document.body.appendChild(parentElm);
}

function removeElement(element) {
    if (element.remove) {
        element.remove(); // newer DOM method, not on all browsers
    } else if (element.parentNode) {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
}

addParagraphs();
removeElement(document.getElementById("parent"));
```

...because the variables in `addParagraphs` can all be reclaimed.

However, if you create a closure over those variables and you keep it, that can keep the elements in memory longer than you expect:

```
function addParagraphs() {
    var parentElm = document.createElement("div");
    var child1 = document.createElement("p");
    var child2 = document.createElement("p");

    parentElm.id = "parent";
    child1.id = "child1";
    child2.id = "child2";

    child1.innerHTML = "Hello";
    child2.innerHTML = "world"; // Is it a good way 

    parentElm.appendChild(child1);
    parentElm.appendChild(child2);
    document.body.appendChild(parentElm);

    return function() {
        console.log("Hi there");
    };
}

function removeElement(element) {
    if (element.remove) {
        element.remove(); // newer DOM method, not on all browsers
    } else if (element.parentNode) {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
}

var f = addParagraphs();
removeElement(document.getElementById("parent"));
```

The function we return from `addParagraphs` and store in `f` is a *closure* over the context it was created in. In theory, even though the function doesn't use `parentElm`, `child1`, or `child2`, it has a reference to the context where it was created, and that context has a reference to those variables, keeping them in memory. (Modern JavaScript engines can optimize this a bit.) So in theory, as long as we have a reference to `f`, those DOM elements can still exist in memory, kept alive by the variables that are kept alive by the function. It's still not necessarily a *leak*, if you release `f` at some point, but it's useful to remember.

---

Of course, you can also create those elements with less code:

```
var parentElm = document.createElement('p');
parentElm.id = "parent";
parentElm.innerHTML =
    '<p id="child1">Hello</p>' +
    '<p id="child2">world</p>';
document.body.appendChild(parentElm);
```

Or on modern browsers:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    '<p id="parent">' +
        '<p id="child1">Hello</p>' +
        '<p id="child2">world</p>' +
    '</p>'
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Got your point. Just for clarification, when removing removing any node, I need to assign its refferance to some other value like null ? Also need to do smae for its child elements ?

Comment: Thank you sir. Its very help full. Always I fear to do innerHTML due to my less knowledge in memory leak. Now got it. Can you please provide some refferance for dom manipulation with out memory leak ?

Comment: @DineshPatra: *"when removing removing any node, I need to assign its refferance to some other value like null ?"* You're not assigning to "its reference," you're assigning to a variable (or property). You only need to do that if something is going to keep that variable (or property) in memory. But if you're done using the element, assigning `null` to the variable/property is harmless at worst and sometimes useful. Re `innerHTML`: I've never heard of memory leak issues with `innerHTML`. I'm afraid I don't know of good references on this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much sir: